# Compare words in string to cell

Tags: mysql

Given the following:

```
create table original (
dbString VARCHAR(255),
c_Alfa TINYINT(4) Default 0,
c_Bravo TINYINT(4) default 0,
c_Charlie  TINYINT(4) default 0
);

INSERT INTO original (dbString) VALUES
('Charlie Echo Delta',0,0,0),
('Foxtrot Golf Hotel',0,0,0),
('Alfa Oscar Tango',0,0,0),
('Charlie Bravo India',0,0,0);

SET @c_string := 'Alfa Bravo Charlie';
```

Is it possible in mysql to compare the words in the @c_string (words are: Alfa, Bravo and Charlie) to the column *dbString* in the table *original* and check if one ore more words appear in the cell.

Outcome should be

```
+---------------------+------------+------------+------------+
| dbString            | c_Alfa     | c_Bravo    | c_Charlie  |
+---------------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Charlie Echo Delta  | 0          | 0          | 1          |
| Foxtrot Golf Hotel  | 0          | 0          | 0          |
| Alfa Oscar Tango    | 1          | 0          | 0          |
| Charlie Bravo India | 0          | 1          | 1          |
+---------------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

I also created a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8eb2b/1

Comment: One question: why in DBMS? Why not: 1. Use application. 2. Use normalized data?

Comment: Currently this comparison is not made in mysql but in another program. Our server needs to compare data like this about 1 million times a week. Doing this in DBMS might increase the overall performance and this is what i would like to verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT dbString,
       IF(locate('Alfa',dbString), 1, 0) AS c_Alfa,
       IF(locate('Bravo',dbString), 1, 0) AS c_Bravo,
       IF(locate('Charlie',dbString), 1, 0) AS c_Charlie
FROM original;
```

Check [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8eb2b/15)

Comment: Based on your answer this i created this fiddler http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8020ea/1, which gives me the results I need.

Comment: Main things is that have you got solution?

Comment: Yes, I already marked your answer as accepted. My fiddle was just to clarify my desired end result, which was possible based on your post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use LIKE in  where condition, for example:
Query:

```
SELECT * FROM original WHERE dbString LIKE ("%" + @c_string + "%");
```

Comment: This will not work since `LIKE` can not make partial matches with that - and, of course, separate words from match.

Comment: partial mathes can be made using % symbol, and then concat with the @c_string using + symbol.

Comment: Please, re-read the question. `%..%` won't work if you'll substitute entire string.